# Free sound editor / converter?

Tags: audio

I'm looking for something like paint.net or Gimp, but for audio files, and runs on windows.

Comment: How does this even have any upvotes? ***This question is off-topic!***

Comment: @cybermonkey: The question is 5 years old. The rules for SO where quite different back then. The good old Middle Ages...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) is fantastic

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Anyway, I'll second that.  Check out Audacity.

Comment: ... AND opensource AND portable. All of which are plus points for any tool!

Comment: Having used several non-free tools for audio I would be very reluctant to say that Audacity is "fantastic". It is the best free audio tool around, however.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, Audacity is fantastic.  If you're looking to batch convert sound files at the command line, check out [mencoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu) and (for MP3s only) [LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

Audacity is painfully limited.  If you are looking to do something a little more complicated.  You should check out Reaper.  It has a 60 day free trial and if you are still doing editing and recording after that long, the price to buy is extremely cheap when compared to other fully functional editing software.  Pro Tools is crazy expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use REAPER for "complex" tasks (tracking, mastering, batch processing) and Audacity for basic cutting/normalizing/exporting to MP3.

If you need free alternative for Audacity for basic mono or stereo file processing, you may try Wavosaur or other software that has realtime previews.

Answer (score -1):

NCH Wavepad is also the best application for the audio. it's easy to understand

Comment: Audacity (Freeware Audio Editor)

Answer (score -1):

Reaper has always worked very well for me. It is free to download and try for 60 days and requires a cheap license after that (there are two different price options). Highly recommended.

Here is the website link:

http://www.reaper.fm/